# Algorithmic complexity of PHP function strlen()

Tags: php, algorithm, complexity-theory

Recently I was asked this question on interview and I didn't know how to answer it.

Can anyone answer this question and describe it?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

O(1) since the length is stored as an attribute: [source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php#13102)

However, this trivia is worth ***countering*** with a discussion about micro-optimising theatre, as kindly provided by our hosts [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/01/the-sad-tragedy-of-micro-optimization-theater.html) and [here](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/fog0000000319.html); read those two links and you'll find a good talking point to change the momentum of the conversation next time similar questions come up, regardless of whether you know the particular answer!

How the interviewer reacts to your tangent will tell you a lot about how much you want to work with them..

Comment: Thank you. Could you give some more similar articles to read? What about interviewer - he was looking for developer with much stronger qualification than I have and this question was not "just for fun". But it gave me better knowledge about my skill weaknesses.

Comment: +1 for "micro-optimization theater."  Profile, [profile](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler), [profile](http://mirror.facebook.net/facebook/xhprof/doc.html)!

Comment: The interviewer was likely reading a prepared list of questions?  Even at Google.  The sooner you take them off the track the better.

Comment: I don't see where your source mentions that string length is stored as an attribute.

Comment: @Nikolai seems they have cleaned up the documentation in the last 3 years.  However, you can also infer it from the fact that null characters do not terminate a string - `strlen( "te\0st" ) = 5` is mentioned in the comments.

Comment: Whatever you were citing as a source appears to have been removed.

Comment: Comparing one O(n) string concatenation implementation vs. some other O(n) string concatenation implementation is probably micro-optimization theater.  Knowing whether `strlen` is O(1) or O(n) can have a huge impact; just look at how [`sscanf`'s unexpected O(n) implementation led to O(n^2) parsing](https://nee.lv/2021/02/28/How-I-cut-GTA-Online-loading-times-by-70/).

Comment: It's probably best not to throw accusations of "micro-optimisation theatre" around if you don't actually *know* that it's theatre. Getting it right first time is much easier than maybe profiling later which very often [just doesn't happen](https://nee.lv/2021/02/28/How-I-cut-GTA-Online-loading-times-by-70/).

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that function is O(n) because it would need to iterate through the string once.

Comment: And why would it need to do that? You're assuming it's stored as an array of chars with no additional information.

Comment: Because that is the right answer, it will obviously not be quadratic and worse than linear.