# How to use Apple's php 5.3 with MAMP

Tags: php, macos, osx-lion, mamp, iconv

There is a bug in php 5.3 with the iconv module. Apple applied a patch for their version of php. However, MAMP didn't include this patch and is thus unusable with Zend Framework (for example).

I tried to include Apple's version of php 5.3 into the MAMP's httpd.conf, but ran into problems with symbols which could not be found. Does anyone know of a proper way to use MAMP with php 5.3 /w iconv? Is recompiling or linking apple's version an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this leave a whole lot of value in the MAMP, but you probably are best served compiling your own php and apache.

http://fabien.potencier.org/article/37/php-5-3-0-on-mac-os-10-6-snow-leopard

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Right now I'm building the dev environment again with use of MacPorts. Tutorials: [link](http://systems.takizo.com/2011/07/22/os-x-lion-macports-1/) and [link](http://blog.ryanparman.com/2009/07/11/installing-php-5-3-with-mysqlnd-on-mac-os-x-with-macports/)

Answer (score 3):

Just rename the php directories in /Applications/MAMP/bin/php
Duplicate php 5.3 directory and rename it to the same ver number of 5.2, and it works. :d

Answer (score 0):

There is a discussion of this issue here:
[iconv_strlen function causing execution timeout, running on MAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400154/iconv-strlen-function-causing-execution-timeout-running-on-mamp)

The basic solution is either to downgrade your MAMP to version 1.9.4 which is the last stable version as far as “iconv” is concerned. Or you can use any version of MAMP from 1.9.5 onwards but switch the PHP version from the MAMP preferences from 5.3 to 5.2.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I decided to configure it using Homebrew instead of using MAMP and MacPorts. It was fairly easy and gives me more flexibility.