# Can you rewrite php function without iconv_substr?

Tags: php, function, timeout, mamp

```
    for ($count = 0; $count < $strLength; $count++) {
        $this->_queryString[$count] = iconv_substr($inputString, $count, 1, $encoding);
    }
```

Can you rewrite the php function above by replacing iconv_substr with another function?  I need to do this because my MAMP version seems to [timeout on iconv_strlen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5400154/iconv-strlen-function-causing-execution-timeout-running-on-mamp).

Answer (score 1):

Use `mb_substr` instead if multibyte extensions are available for your PHP installation

```
$this->_queryString[$count] = mb_substr($inputString, $count, 1, $encoding);
```