# Broken iconv PHP extension detected, installation can not continue

Tags: php, mamp, moodle, iconv

I have downloaded Moodle and extracted zip file. then i have placed this moodle in MAMP/htdocs. Now i am browsing from localhost:8888/moodle, i am geting these following error.
"Broken iconv PHP extension detected, installation can not continue.". How can i fix it?

Answer (score 1):

You question is actually offtopic (hope this get moved), Moodle does not work with every version of MAMP. You need to find a version of MAMP that works with Moodle in your case.

- [Moodle MDL-28635 - Backport broken iconv detection to STABLE](http://tracker.moodle.org/browse/MDL-28635)

> The MAMP is known to have completely broken icon extension, no Moodle version that requires iconv can work with that. I suppose there should be some bold letter warning, the only trouble is that some users will not believe us as usually...
>
> The Moodle 2.2dev will stop the install and upgrades completely if broken iconv detected, I am not sure that is the bast solution for stable.
>
> This is a blocker because any data processed by broken iconv is completely lost...

You might need to update or downgrade your MAMP setup, the ICONV problem was fixed in MAMP / MAMP PRO 2.0.2. See as well [Broken iconv php extension MAMP](http://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=183176).

Related:

- [iconv_strlen function causing execution timeout, running on MAMP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5400154/367456)
- [Bug #43189 Fails to link iconv](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=43189)
- [Bug #48195 iconv link failure](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=48195)
- [Bug #49267 Linking fails for iconv: "Undefined symbols: _libiconv"](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=49267)
- [PHP 5.3.0 on Mac OS 10.6 (Snow Leopard) - Fabien Potencier;
  05 Nov 2009](http://fabien.potencier.org/article/37/php-5-3-0-on-mac-os-10-6-snow-leopard)

Answer (score 0):

15 secs of googling.

look at link below, seems legit.

http://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=183176