# What algorithmic complexity has strlen() in PHP?

Tags: algorithm

This question I've received during interview. My answer is O(1), is it correct?

Comment: This depends on the implementation.

Comment: what interview is this for, college professor? I haven't used those terms since I graduated college almost 20 years ago

Comment: In one social network company )) (no fb)

Comment: This was answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292325/algorithmic-complexity-of-php-function-strlen

Comment: Voting to close as a duplicate of [Algorithmic complexity of PHP function strlen()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292325/algorithmic-complexity-of-php-function-strlen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If strlen counts each character in the string, then it's O(n).  If the String class holds a length in some private variable, then it's O(1).

Comment: I've purpose that their didn't count chars ))

Comment: And if the designers of PHP wanted to be uncool about it, they could make it have any complexity at all. Kind of a strange, memorization-based question to ask.

Comment: @Patrick87 strlen can't have "no complexity". Usually it is either O(1) or O(n), n being the number of characters. It can be even O(n!) or O(∞), but such strlen algorithms are never used in practice.

Comment: @WTP: Not sure that I said it could have "no complexity"... just that it could have any complexity, as you illustrate. When we say that an integer variable can have any of the values between 1 and 10, we typically mean that it must have one of them... sort of implicit. And whether or not inefficient strlen() implementations are used in practice is an empirical question; to answer it, you'd need (in this instance) to actually check the PHP implementation... unless you assume viable programming languages use efficient implementations, which - however reasonable - represents a leap of faith.

Comment: @Patrick87 sorry, I misunderstood your first comment. I read "make it have **no** complexity at all."