# PHP: return length of each array Element or stop

Tags: php, arrays, cost-based-optimizer

given I have an array, say:

```
$myArray=['12','AB','3C']
```

I want to return the value 2 (which is the length of each of the array elements indivudually.)

But in case I have something like

```
$myArray=['12','AB2','3C']
```

I want to **stop the calculation/loop right after the second element** of the array `'AB2'` and let my function return null.

What is the most effective way to reach this in the matter of being performance and speed effective? Since such an array can get long.

Comment: This is quite straightforward, post code you've tried and highlight what's giving you trouble.

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Casual way

I think you are trying to stop the array loop the moment you get two different lengths in an element?

In that case, at worst, you'd need an `O(n)` runtime (since you need to verify every element, unless you have an abstract data type in mind in which case it could be `O(1)`, if it is stored in the object property or you calculate the difference detected on the fly while pushing items into arrays)

Since the moment we discover an element is not the same length, we can simply quickly store the length of the first element in the array since we know if we detect any other length other than what we stored, we can immediately return `null`

```
function linear_loop($array) {
    $len_of_first = strlen($array[0]);
    foreach ($array as $val) {
        if (strlen($val) != $len_of_first) {
            return null;
        }
    }
    //Function still running, entire array was same, return the length of first element
    return $len_of_first;
}
```

This function is `O(n)` with each operation is constant. `strlen` is `O(1)`

[Algorithmic complexity of PHP function strlen()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5292325/algorithmic-complexity-of-php-function-strlen)

#### Most "performance-fastest"

Since you said that the array can get quite long, if you are not immediately generating the array, but rather you need to push items into it, then in your push operation, you can check before pushing it the `item_to_be_pushed` is the same `strlen` or whatever property you are trying to compare as the one you've stored (which can be picked arbitrarily, since the array must be of uniform some `property`)

In this case, you could have some `object` with `property`: `uniform_length` and store that. Then whenever you `push` into your array, you can check against it with the `uniform_length`. If it isn't the same length, then you can store in the object property called `uniform` as false. (By default `uniform` is true since if there is only one element in the array, it must be uniform).

This would be an `O(1)` calculation since it is stored as an attribute. But you probably don't need an object for something as simple as this, and you can just store it as some variable.

#### O(1) vs O(n) Runtime and why it is more performance effective

Since not everyone knows Big O, a quick explanation on what I said. `O(1)` runtime is "infinitely" better than `O(n)` runtime since the runtime of the function will not grow with input (as in processing 1 million items require the same amount of steps as processing 1 item)

Answer (score 2):

Just loop through and return early when you find something that isn't correct. Don't worry about micro-optimizations until you have profiled and found that this function is really your bottleneck

ex.

```
function isCorrect($arr) {
   $len = strlen($arr[0]);
   for($arr as $val) {
      if(strlen($val) != $len) {
          return false;
      }
   }
   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just my two cents. You could also use `array_map` for this:

```
$myArray = ['12','AB','3CC'];
$lengths = array_map('strlen', $myArray);
// output
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 3
)
```

you can just write an `if` statement and check the `max($lengths)` and return `true or false`

-Cheers